# BeautifulSoup parse special character

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I extract text from links with BeautifulSoup like:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
 response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
 html = response.read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

 #print(soup)
 for a in soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"link"}):
  print(a.text)
```

But I get some characters like "`&#8211`" for a simple "`-`".
How to get these characters readable for Humans?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"link"}):
  print(a.get_text())
```